# Not able to install Bioconductor packages due to proxy

Tags: r, proxy, centos6, bioconductor

I am not able to install Bio-conductor packages due to proxy. I was having the same issue with CRAN packages also, and I fixed it by using

```
install.packages('package_name', dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
```

But Bio-conductor packages are giving me a tough time. I have set proxy and checked it using

```
Sys.getenv("http_proxy")
[1] "http://proxy.staff.ac.in:3128"
Sys.getenv("https_proxy")
[1] "https://proxy.staff.ac.in:3128"
Sys.getenv("ftp_proxy")
[1] "ftp://proxy.staff.ac.in:3128"
```

When I try to install the packages by `BiocManager::install("affy")`, I get the following error

```
Bioconductor version 3.8 (BiocManager 1.30.4), R 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Installing package(s) 'BiocVersion', 'affy'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.8/bioc/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.8/bioc/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.8/data/annotation/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.8/data/annotation/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.8/data/experiment/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.8/data/experiment/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.8/workflows/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.8/workflows/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.8/bioc/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.8/bioc/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.8/data/annotation/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.8/data/annotation/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.8/data/experiment/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.8/data/experiment/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.8/workflows/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.8/workflows/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning message:
packages ‘BiocVersion’, ‘affy’ are not available (for R version 3.5.1)
```

Here is the session information:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS release 6.9 (Final)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_IN       LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=en_IN       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_IN     LC_MONETARY=en_IN    LC_MESSAGES=en_IN   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_IN       LC_NAME=C            LC_ADDRESS=C        
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IN LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] BiocManager_1.30.4 compiler_3.5.1     tools_3.5.1
```

Comment: proxies are usually defined in the .Renviron file. If that is the case, removing .Renviron can resolve your issue. Although that might violate your institutions rules so you might want to check that first.

Comment: @Maylo Thank your for your comment, that is not the solution.